# VBA Execute Macros for Word Document in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an excel calculation which contains information for a Word Document. What I want is to open the word document and save it as an pdf automatically - with a macro in Excel.

I already tried the following:

```
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With WordApp.Application
   .Visible = True
   .Documents.Open (LocationTemplate)
        .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        OfferPath, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        DestinationPath
    .Quit

End With
```

What is the mistake? Looking forward to your support.

Comment: Please tell us a little bit more about your problem: Do you get an error? Does it work in unexpected ways? (We can't check your code, as long as you don't provide us with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - as your snippet simply doesn't compile for me due to lacking declarations.)

Comment: After the Word Document opened I got Run time error 438. The yellow markings start at .ExportAsFixedFormat.

Comment: Can you please edit that information into your question - I think it is crucial to solving your problem. Also, have a look at my answer and see if it helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a final solution with the help of your answers. Nevertheless I am still trying to fix. 
A second way is that the Word includes an `AutoOpen` macro and can thereby save the file as an PDF. Therefore I need the Path of the excel calculation. Is there a possiblity to transfer the path (probably as a variable) from excel to word?

Comment: You won't succeed with `AutoOpen` either. You first need to fix the problem in your code. Your `.ExportAsFixedFormat` method refers to the wrong object. As mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52294591/7778672) and in [Cindy Meister's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317628/7778672) answer as well.

Comment: You haven't marked any of the contributions as an Answer, nor upvoted any of them. Did any of the contributions help you or answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that youre not selecting the open document

try something like this

```
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With WordApp.Application
  .Visible = True
  .Documents.Open (LocationTemplate)

  .Activate

  ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat 
    .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    OfferPath, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
    DestinationPath
  .Quit

End With
```

Good Luck

Comment: Did you try to compile/run your code? Your suggestion will exhibit the same behavior as OP's code snippet (I.e. Error 438). `.ExportAsFixedFormat` does not exist on the `WordApp` object.

Comment: yes, ive tryied and worked. in the wordapp doenst exist, but in the activedocument yes... and thats why u activate the document.

Comment: I'm referring to the line `ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat ` (which should work), followed by `.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _` [...] which I'm quite sure won't work. (As it's calling `ExportAsFixedFormat` on `Word.Application`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed `Wordapp` as a `Word.Application`instead of an object. Nevertheless, I get an compile error, because `.ExportAsFixedFormat` does not exist. Is there a possiblity to add it? 
Generally my question is not only connected to `.ExportAsFixedFormat`. I want access to the word document with the macros in Excel.

Comment: @LuisCurado Now I'm getting what you're trying to achieve. The method `ExportAsFixedFormat` is available on every object of the type `Word.Document`. You don't need `ActiveDocument` for this. (And thus there is no need to first call `.Activate`). If you set a reference to the document you're opening like `Set doc = .Documents.Open(LocationTemplate)`, you can then use `doc.ExportAsFixedFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

### Runtime Error 438: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Your problem stems from the fact that in the `With` block you are referring to `WordApp.Application` (which in itself is redundant and could be reduced to `WordApp` as it already represents a `Word.Application` object) and thus with the line `.ExportAsFixedFormat [...]` you are essentially doing:

`Word.Application.ExportAsFixedFormat`

This method doesn't exist on the `Application` object. (Now read the error description again - notice anything?)

If you instead of late-binding the `Word.Application` object via `CreateObject()` set a reference to the Word Object Model (Menu: Extras - References) you can do things like:

```
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Set wordApp = New Word.Application
With wordApp.Documents.Open LocationTemplate
    .ExportAsFixedFormat [...]
End With
```

Which provides you with the (much needed) intellisense, as well as compile-time errors instead of runtime errors when you try to call wrong methods.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you execute `.ExportAsFixedFormat` on the Word.Application object. This method is valid for a *Word document*. Your code should be more like what follows.

Note that I've added the variable declarations for `WordApp` and `WordDoc` and also code to *release* these objects.

```
Dim WordApp as Object
Dim WordDoc as Object
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With WordApp.Application
   .Visible = True
   Set WordDoc = .Documents.Open (LocationTemplate)
   WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        OfferPath, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    .Quit 0 'To not save changes to the document, just close it
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
End With
Set WordApp = Nothing
```